# How to disable user validation in ASP.NET MVC Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am learning ASP.net MVC and want to know how to disable user validation in Microsoft Identity, when a user register. Please help[This is the register screen I want to remove validation for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awbS9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that you've not changed much in the application so far I'd suggest creating a new one. You turn off Authentication when you create the application - rather than trying to remove all the code and configuration in place to enable authentication.

When you setup the project click 'Change Authentication' and set it to 'No Authentication'

[image: Turn Off]

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I just wanted to know where is the code and how to customize it.

Comment: @RajbeerSingh customize it how?

Comment: Like at present it is forcing to enter atleast 6 character password, I could change to 10 or 5. Or I can add more fields to it.

Comment: @RajbeerSingh I'd suggest posting a new question on 'changing password length validation in MVC' and 'how to add more fields to MVC register form'